# How to limit list in python to show N records for each unique row?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am trying to limit mysql output of query to show only Top N records for each genre. This is my code :

```
def selectTopNactors(n):

# Create a new connection
con=connection()

# Create a cursor on the connection
cur=con.cursor()
#execute query
int(n)
sql ="""SELECT g.genre_name, a.actor_id,COUNT(mg.genre_id) as num_mov
FROM actor as a, role as r,movie as m,genre as g, movie_has_genre as mg
WHERE a.actor_id = r.actor_id AND m.movie_id = r.movie_id
      AND m.movie_id = mg.movie_id AND g.genre_id = mg.genre_id
      AND (g.genre_id, m.movie_id) IN (SELECT g.genre_id, m.movie_id
       FROM movie as m, genre as g, movie_has_genre as mg
       WHERE m.movie_id = mg.movie_id AND mg.genre_id = g.genre_id 
       ORDER BY g.genre_id)
       GROUP BY g.genre_name, a.actor_id
       ORDER BY g.genre_name, COUNT(*) desc """

cur.execute(sql)

results = cur.fetchall()


listab = []
listac = []
for row in results:
     lista = []
     lista.append(row[0])
     lista.append(row[1])
     lista.append(row[2])
     listab = tuple(lista)
     listac.append(listab)
head = ("genreName","actorId","numberOfMovies")    
listac.insert(0,head) 


print (n)
con.commit()
return listac
```

And the list which is returning it is huge (6000+) records, So I want to show only N records for each genre.
returned list is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2u45196xfb00wo/actor.html?dl=0)

Comment: Suggestion: ditch the old school comma syntax for the join operations, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead, and relocate the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an appropriate `ON` clause.

Comment: @spencer7593 thank you for your answer , but this will not work for me because I need user input for N, so I think the trick will be in python part.

Comment: That wasn't an answer, that was a comment. My comment was a suggestion, intended to aid readers in understand the SQL. It makes it more obvious that the `(tuple) in (subquery)` mess is redundant, that part of the query can be omitted.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood :)

Answer (score 1):

In version of MySQL before 8.0, we can emulate analytic functions using user-defined variables in carefully crafted queries. Note that we are depending on behavior of user-defined variables that is not guaranteed (documented in the MySQL Reference Manual).

```
SELECT @rn := IF(c.genre_name=@prev_genre,@rn+1,1) AS rn
     , @prev_genre := c.genre_name                 AS genre_name
     , c.actor_id                                  AS actor_id
     , c.num_mov                                   AS num_mov
  FROM ( SELECT @prev_genre := NULL, @rn := 0 ) i
 CROSS 
  JOIN ( SELECT g.genre_name
              , a.actor_id
              , COUNT(1) AS num_mov
           FROM actor a
           JOIN role r
             ON r.actor_id = a.actor_id
           JOIN movie m
             ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id
           JOIN movie_has_genre mg
             ON mg.movie_id = m.movie_id
           JOIN genre g
             ON g.genre_id = mg.genre_id
          GROUP
             BY g.genre_name
              , a.actor_id
          ORDER
             BY g.genre_name
              , COUNT(1) DESC
              , a.actor_id
       ) c
 ORDER
    BY c.genre_name
     , c.num_mov DESC
     , c.actor_id
HAVING rn <= 4
```

The literal `4` at the end of the query represents the value **`N`** in the question.

In MySQL 8.0, we can use the newly introduced analytic functions, to obtain an equivalent result:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.genre_name ORDER BY c.num_mov DESC, c.actor_id)
       AS rn
     , c.genre_name                                 AS genre_name
     , c.actor_id                                   AS actor_id
     , c.num_mov                                    AS num_mov
  FROM ( SELECT g.genre_name
              , a.actor_id
              , COUNT(1) AS num_mov
           FROM actor a
           JOIN role r
             ON r.actor_id = a.actor_id
           JOIN movie m
             ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id
           JOIN movie_has_genre mg
             ON mg.movie_id = m.movie_id
           JOIN genre g
             ON g.genre_id = mg.genre_id
          GROUP
             BY g.genre_name
              , a.actor_id
          ORDER
             BY g.genre_name
              , COUNT(1) DESC
              , a.actor_id
       ) c
 ORDER
    BY c.genre_name
     , c.num_mov DESC
     , c.actor_id
HAVING rn <= 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your analytic and nice answer, I have mySql 8.0 and mySql Workbench 8.0, I get xytax error, I think RowNumber ( ) is not recognized by mySql.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number  I've not yet used the analytic functions in MySQL 8.0 ... the example provided is my best guess at it.  The user-defined variable approach works in MySQL 5.6 and 5.7, I'd expect that would still work in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I have tried to run it as sql query on Workbench and it gives me a syntax error.